# Installing Keras in new environment

Tags: python, keras, anaconda, environment

In order to do several deep learning tasks in Python, I want to have TensorFlow, Theano en Keras installed on my computer.

As these are packages created for Python 3.5, I have created a new environment using:

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda
```

Then, after I have activated py35, I have installed Theano and TensorFlow:

```
conda install theano 
conda install tensorflow
```

After I run Spyder at this point, it still launches. However, if I install Keras as well (code from: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/keras):

```
conda install -c conda-forge keras
```

And try to run Spyder afterwards, I get the following error:

*'Python has stopped working - A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program.'*

What can I do to install Keras in my environment and not get this error?

Comment: try to kill instances of conda and python before you run your last command (pkill conda     pkill python3)

Comment: If I run: 'pkill conda pkill python3', I get: " 'pkill' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program of batch file.". And if I try: 'conda pkill conda pkill python3', I get: "CommandNotFoundError: No command 'conda pkill'.". Can you tell me what code I can use to kill conda and python instances?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is wise to install Anaconda in an Anaconda env. I would suggest you create an environment and install just spyder within it. Then try installing tf/theano and keras and report the results.

Comment: Does that mean that when I create py35, the code should be: 

    _conda create -n py35 python=3.5_ 

rather than:

    _conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda_?

Comment: you don't have pkill ?!? What is your OS?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: My OS is Windows

Comment: My  bad, the equivalent on Win is [taskkill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill) (syntax of which I don't know)

Comment: @DocDriven, your suggestion does not work. I get the same error and can't start Spyder anymore.

Comment: That's expected as spyder is not present in the env anymore. Install it via `conda install spyder` and try starting it again.

Comment: I did that already. First, I ran `conda create -n py35 python=3.5`. Then, I ran `conda install spyder`. Installed the package as listed above and then ran Spyder again, which resulted in this error.

Comment: How do you start spyder? Via console or navigator?

Comment: @David Zarebski, if I look for all my open tasks using `tasklist`, neither conda nor python3 are listed. So, there is nothing to kill.

Comment: @DocDriven, via the Command Prompt. Because I run it from my new Python 3.5 environment.

Comment: I have found some reports on this. It might be that Win 10 has a problem with the newest Anaconda version, so you might try downgrading.

Comment: Does any of you have any further idea?